# .NET api to extract file contents of different file types

Tags: .net, file

I'm trying to make a e discovery software for my major project. Can anyone suggest open source api for extracting file contents and saving to another format or a database. I'm thinking of mining from different files and saving them to my own format or a database. File type includes all office type files,emails,pdf. Something similar to "Stellent" would be good but opensource. Please I could not find any good api.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Comment: can i use this to convert any file types and save to database??

Comment: Your question says *nothing* about conversion or databases. You're asking for file properties, and this class provides that (last modification time etc). See [ask].

Comment: sorry about that. Now can you help please.

Comment: If you want to extract text from these file types, you can use [TikaOnDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a .Net wrapper for Apache Tika - [TikaOnDotNet](https://kevm.github.io/tikaondotnet/)

This will extract text from a large variety of file types.